# Why variable value is not refreshing in flutter?

Tags: flutter

The variable value is not refreshing in flutter(which I created outside the class). The following way I have added.So in button press am setting different value. So if I come back to that screen again it is not showing 1. May I know why it is happening?

```
int _currVal = 1;

class AskFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "//";
  static const
  int currState = -1;

  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}
```

Comment: variables change state inside a StatefulWidget, if you want to change that value, use the method setState(). You're using a global variable that way and you won't get the updated value when changed.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla yeah it is global value only. Am using an Alert dialog in that am setting the value. Am getting the value. But the problem is what ever I got the last value it is remains state. if I come back to the particular screen

Comment: initialize the value inside the class and update the value in setState((){}); :- read this document :- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: @YogeshChawla done

Comment: is it working now ? @SunishaSindhu

Comment: @YogeshChawla I have added that in initState

Comment: is the value refreshing then ?

Comment: @YogeshChawla yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208103/discussion-between-sunisha-sindhu-and-yogesh-chawla).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the values, use Stateful Widget and initialise values inside that Widget only, for any updates in the values of variables mention that in `setState((){})` method to notify the change in the values.

[See this for documentation of stateful widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

[See this for documentation of setState((){}) method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

```
setState(() { _myVariable = newValue });
```

**Note:-** Never initialise changing values in build method they will not get updated instead they will be reinitialised with same values again and again

Comment: Your "Note" part saved my day, thanks!